# Symlink error in google colab while installing meshroom

Tags: google-colaboratory, meshroom

After running below command

```
!wget -N https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom/releases/download/v2019.2.0/Meshroom-2019.2.0-linux.tar.gz
!mkdir meshroom
!tar xzf Meshroom-2019.2.0-linux.tar.gz -C ./meshroom
```

I get the below error in google colab please provide an alternative or solution for it.

```
Meshroom-2019.2.0-l 100%[===================>] 409.38M  14.1MB/s    in 32s     

2019-12-14 09:50:21 (12.6 MB/s) - ‘Meshroom-2019.2.0-linux.tar.gz’ saved [429271659/429271659]

tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/qtPlugins/qml/AliceVision/libqtAliceVisionPlugin.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘libqtAliceVisionPlugin.so.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/qtPlugins/qml/AliceVision/libqtAliceVisionPlugin.so.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libqtAliceVisionPlugin.so.0.1’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/qtPlugins/qml/AlembicEntity/libalembicEntityQmlPlugin.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘libalembicEntityQmlPlugin.so.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/qtPlugins/qml/AlembicEntity/libalembicEntityQmlPlugin.so.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libalembicEntityQmlPlugin.so.0.1’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportPMVS: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportPMVS-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_cameraInit: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_cameraInit-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_computeStructureFromKnownPoses: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_computeStructureFromKnownPoses-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_convertLDRToHDR: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_convertLDRToHDR-0.1’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_globalSfM: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_globalSfM-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_sfmLocalization: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_sfmLocalization-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_meshFiltering: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_meshFiltering-3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_cameraCalibration: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_cameraCalibration-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_sfmTransform: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_sfmTransform-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_imageMatching: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_imageMatching-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_sfmColorHarmonize: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_sfmColorHarmonize-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMVSTexturing: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMVSTexturing-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_voctreeQueryUtility: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_voctreeQueryUtility-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportTracks: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportTracks-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_rigCalibration: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_rigCalibration-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_incrementalSfM: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_incrementalSfM-2.1’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_qualityEvaluation: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_qualityEvaluation-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMatlab: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMatlab-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_meshResampling: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_meshResampling-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_featureMatching: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_featureMatching-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMVE2: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMVE2-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_frustumFiltering: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_frustumFiltering-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_meshDecimate: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_meshDecimate-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_voctreeStatistics: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_voctreeStatistics-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_convertSfMFormat: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_convertSfMFormat-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_cameraLocalization: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_cameraLocalization-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMatches: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMatches-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_depthMapFiltering: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_depthMapFiltering-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_prepareDenseScene: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_prepareDenseScene-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMeshroomMaya: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMeshroomMaya-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_rigLocalization: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_rigLocalization-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_split360Images: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_split360Images-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportMeshlab: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportMeshlab-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_sfmAlignment: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_sfmAlignment-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportColoredPointCloud: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportColoredPointCloud-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_voctreeCreation: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_voctreeCreation-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_texturing: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_texturing-3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportCameraFrustums: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportCameraFrustums-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportAnimatedCamera: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportAnimatedCamera-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_meshing: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_meshing-3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_rigTransform: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_rigTransform-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_exportKeypoints: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_exportKeypoints-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_convertFloatDescriptorToUchar: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_convertFloatDescriptorToUchar-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_depthMapEstimation: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_depthMapEstimation-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_convertRAW: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_convertRAW-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_utils_keyframeSelection: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_utils_keyframeSelection-2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_meshDenoising: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_meshDenoising-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/bin/aliceVision_featureExtraction: Cannot create symlink to ‘aliceVision_featureExtraction-1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libgfortran.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgfortran.so.3.0.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_multiview.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_multiview.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libcolamd.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libcolamd.so.2.9.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libgomp.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgomp.so.1.0.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/liblapack.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘liblapack.so.3.8.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_gpu.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_gpu.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libceres.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libceres.so.1.14.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libIlmThread-2_3.so.24: Cannot create symlink to ‘libIlmThread-2_3.so.2.3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_sfmData.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_sfmData.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_matching.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_matching.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libraw_r.so.19: Cannot create symlink to ‘libraw_r.so.19.0.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_kvld.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_kvld.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libIlmImf-2_3.so.24: Cannot create symlink to ‘libIlmImf-2_3.so.2.3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libcamd.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libcamd.so.2.4.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libtiff.so.5: Cannot create symlink to ‘libtiff.so.5.4.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libsuitesparseconfig.so.4: Cannot create symlink to ‘libsuitesparseconfig.so.4.5.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_localization.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_localization.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libz.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libz.so.1.2.11’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libAlembic.so.1.7: Cannot create symlink to ‘libAlembic.so.1.7.11’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_numeric.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_numeric.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_videoio.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libHalf-2_3.so.24: Cannot create symlink to ‘libHalf-2_3.so.2.3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_fuseCut.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_fuseCut.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_lInftyComputerVision.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_lInftyComputerVision.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_sensorDB.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_sensorDB.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libccolamd.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libccolamd.so.2.9.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libspqr.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libspqr.so.2.0.8’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_depthMap.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_depthMap.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_mvsData.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_mvsData.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_feature.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_feature.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_rig.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_rig.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_colorHarmonization.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_colorHarmonization.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_sfmDataIO.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_sfmDataIO.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_keyframe.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_keyframe.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_matchingImageCollection.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_matchingImageCollection.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_calibration.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_calibration.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libjpeg.so.62: Cannot create symlink to ‘libjpeg.so.62.2.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libgeogram.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgeogram.so.1.6.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libblas.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘libblas.so.3.8.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libquadmath.so.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libquadmath.so.0.0.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libIex-2_3.so.24: Cannot create symlink to ‘libIex-2_3.so.2.3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_sfm.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_sfm.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libpng16.so.16: Cannot create symlink to ‘libpng16.so.16.34.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libcudart.so.7.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libcudart.so.7.0.28’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libcublas.so.7.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libcublas.so.7.0.28’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libImath-2_3.so.24: Cannot create symlink to ‘libImath-2_3.so.2.3.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libamd.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libamd.so.2.4.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libgeogram_num_3rdparty.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgeogram_num_3rdparty.so.1.6.6’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_system.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_system.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_mvsUtils.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_mvsUtils.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_video.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libgeogram_num_3rdparty.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgeogram_num_3rdparty.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_hdr.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_hdr.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_track.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_track.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_features2d.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libcholmod.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘libcholmod.so.3.0.11’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libOpenImageIO.so.2.0: Cannot create symlink to ‘libOpenImageIO.so.2.0.10’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_flann.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_image.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_image.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_mesh.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_mesh.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘libopencv_core.so.4.1.0’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_dataio.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_dataio.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_voctree.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_voctree.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Meshroom-2019.2.0/aliceVision/lib/libaliceVision_geometry.so.2: Cannot create symlink to ‘libaliceVision_geometry.so.2.2’: Operation not supported
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I tried some possible solutions but here i am directly using my drive to do the task.
I don't know any details like this to eradicate such problems it has taken a lot of time to get my hands overit please look into the error i used the opensource meshroom tool for 3d image but results are not getting out.
I am sorry to write such things but stackoverflow is not allowing me to submit my question as it thinks there are no details here and only the messy code is present which is clueless.
Anyways solution for this please.